# Angularfire2 Class to add to the database the data of a logged user

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am doing the service to add in the database the user logged data but I have a problem with my class

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

var adminConection=null;

export class setAdmin {    
    constructor(public af: AngularFire){}
    setDataAdmin(admin:any){         
        adminConection=this.af.database.object('/admins/'+admin.uid);
        adminConection.set({
            uid:admin.uid,
            email:admin.email,
            emailVerified:admin.emailVerified,
            displayName:admin.displayName,
            photoURL:admin.photoURL,
            type:1 //Type (admin)
        }).then(_ => console.log('success'));  
    }
}
```

"Can't resolve all parameters for setAdmin: (?)."

Comment: I already solved it I needed to import a component
`import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";`

Comment: Hi SebaS. You should add that in as answer. :)